# Как в cmake правильно копировать библиотеки при установке?

Tags: c++, cmake

### Что я делаю

Пусть у меня есть вот такая структура проекта

```
SuperProject/
  _build/
      my_lib1.dll
      my_lib2.dll
      Qt6Core.dll
      Qt6Guid.dll
      Coin4.dll
      AnyLib.dll
      main.exe
  _install/
      bin/
          main.exe
      lib/
          my_lib1.dll
          my_lib2.dll
      include/
          ...   
  src/
      ...
```

**1** Библиотеки `my_lib1` и `my_lib2` это мои библиотеки, я их собираю из исходников.

**2** Библиотеки `Qt6Core.dll` и `Qt6Guid.dll` копируются в папку **_build** с помощью windeployqt.

```
add_custom_command(TARGET ${target} POST_BUILD
        COMMAND "${_qt_bin_dir}/windeployqt.exe"
                \"$<TARGET_FILE:${target}>\"
)
```

**3** Библиотеки `Coin4.dll` и `AnyLib.dll` копируются с помощью такой команды.

```
add_custom_command(TARGET main POST_BUILD
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different
    $<$<CONFIG:Debug>:C:/Coin3D/bin/Coin4d.dll>
    $<$<NOT:$<CONFIG:Debug>>:C:/Coin3D/bin/Coin4.dll>
    $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:main>
)
```

### Проблема

С пунктом **1** проблем никаких нет.

С пунктами **2** и **3** проблема заключается в том, что я не знаю, как копировать файлы в папку `_install`. Т.е. в папку `_build` они копируются с помощью `POST_BUILD` после сборки, а как тогда копировать библиотеку при инсталляции?

### Мои соображения

Мне кажется, что это нужно сделать с помощью команды `install()`, но как? Всю директорию копировать?

Comment: в папку `_install` они копируются с помощью `POST_BUILD` после сборки

Comment: @user7860670 Немного непонятна суть вашего ответа. add_custom_command( ... POST_BUILD ...) будет копировать файлы при сборке проекта. Мне нужно при инсталляции

Comment: При инсталляции этим должен будет заниматься инсталлятор.